# Is it possible to override the assignment ('=') operator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Is there a dunder for this? Perhaps something along the lines of: (updated)

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, item_or_tree):
        self._setto(item_or_tree)

    def __assign__(self, val):
        self._setto(item_or_tree)

    def __setitem__(self, which, to_what):
        ## I would like this to call __assign__ on the Tree object at _tree[which]
        to_what._tree[which] = to_what

    def __getitem__(self, which):
        return self._tree[which]

    def __len__(self): return len(self._tree)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Tree):
            if other._is_tree:
                return (self._item == other._item) and (self._tree == other._tree)
            else:
                return self._item == other._item
        else: return self._item == other

    def _setto(self, item_or_tree):
        if isinstance(item_or_tree, Tree):
            self._set_from_Tree(item_or_tree)
        elif isinstance(item_or_tree, dict):
            self._set_from_dict(item_or_tree)
        else:
            self._set_from_other(item_or_type)


    def _set_from_Tree(self, other_Tree):
        self._tree = other_Tree[:]
        self._item = other_Tree
        self._is_tree = other_Tree._is_tree

    def _set_from_dict(self, the_dict):
        self._is_tree = True
        self._item = None
        self._tree = {}
        for key, val in the_dict.items():
            self._tree[key] = Tree(val)

    def _set_from_other(self, other):
        self._is_tree = False
        self._tree = None
        self._item = other

class TreeModel(Tree, QAbstractItemModel):
    ...
    ## a whole bunch of required overrides
    ## etc
    ...
```

What I'm trying to do is implement a generalized tree structure that acts as intuitively (to me) as possible and also seamlessly integrates with PyQt5's Model-View-Delegate architecture.

I want to be able to set the incoming item_or_tree to either the item or tree. So I'm looking to overload the function that's called when the = operator is used on the item.

PyQt has this item based architecture in which a QAbstractItemModel is overridden. This is (I guess) supposed to return / accept QModelIndex objects. These are trees of tables (2D arrays).

So I'm creating a single tree structure that can contain itself, deal with the 2 opposing indexing paradigms, and plays nice with Python and everything else.

Comment: I think this would violate Python's object model or variable/naming scheme.  A name does not represent one object only, but just points to an object under the hood.  Using the assignment operator just changes the object a name points to.

Comment: Because then, once assigning to a variable it would be impossible to do anything with that label again?

Comment: Nothing could be further from how Python works. Assignment doesn't even *touch* the object, it **only** manipulates names. You should describe what problem you're trying to solve so we can focus on how to achieve that.

Comment: @delnan Ya, that's what I feared. What I'm trying to do is implement a generalized tree object to be able to easily use with the rest of my code and PyQt5's model-view architecture. I'll put the details in the question, just a sec.

Comment: *Property assignments/set'ing* (for a given object) can be intercepted .. not sure if such is any use, or a path worth exploring in context, however. Ref. http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/new-style-classes.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is not possible to override the implementation of `x = y`.  See [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for details of what assignment means.

You can override `x.a = y`, with `__setattr__`, it is (roughly) `x.__setattr__('a', y)`.

You can override `x[k] = y` with `__setitem__`, it is (roughly) `x.__setitem__(k, y)`.

But you can't override `x = y`.

Comment: So sad.. but understandable. Thanks