# Wrap a 1 argument method as a variable change in Python

Tags: python, methods, wrapper

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is even possible:

Basically I got a `config.py` file, it contains some variables, let's say `var1` is one of them.

I want that by doing `config.var1 = 'some value'` what will actually happen is `config.some_method('some value')`

Is that possible?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456448/is-it-possible-to-override-the-assignment-operator-in-python

Comment: well that sucks

Comment: Read the linked answer more carefully: You _can_ do it, as long as `config` is not a module but an object of a class you define. You could even name both `config`, and import it with `from config import config` to keep the rest of your code the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a module.

Use a class, with a `@property`.