# How to implement a matrix with classes

Tags: python, class, matrix

I need to implement a matrix with N cells and these cells depend on K parameters, some fixed and other variables. I would like to do all this through the use of classes.
could someone explain to me the basic procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, I should not answer this since it's a "homework", but I cannot resist a matrix class!!

Basically, a matrix is nothing more than a list of lists. Implementing it as a class means you should add some basic functionalities (methods) like, get the value of a specific row/column, print the matrix etc...

Here a simple one you can start with:

```
class Matrix2D:
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Init an empty matrix.
        '''
        self.matrix = []
        self.rows = 0
        self.columns = 0
        self.name = 'Unnamed'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.matrix

    def generate(self, rows, columns, verbose=False):
        '''
        Return a list of lists containing the indices of the matrix (row, col)
        and prints it by row.
        int, int -> [[(int, int), ...], ...]
        '''
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.matrix = [[(row, col) for col in range(columns)] for row in range(rows)]
        if verbose ==  True:
            print(f'Generated a {self.rows} row/s by {self.columns} column/s matrix')
            print('--------' * columns)
            self.printme()
            print('--------' * columns)
        return self.matrix

    def printme(self, verbose=False):
        '''
        Print the matrix by row.
        '''
        if verbose == True:
            print(f'I am a {self.rows} row/s by {self.columns} column/s matrix')
        for row in self.matrix:
            print(row)

    def get_row(self, n, verbose=False):
        '''
        Return the row n of the matrix.
        '''
        if verbose ==  True:
            print(f'matrix[row={n}]...')
            print(self.matrix[n])
        return self.matrix[n]

    def get_col(self, n, verbose=False):
        '''
        Return the column n of the matrix.
        '''
        column_items = []
        i = 0
        while i < self.rows:
            column_items.append(self.matrix[i][n])
            i += 1
        if verbose ==  True:
            print(f'matrix[col={n}]...')
            for item in column_items:
                print(item)
        return column_items

    def get_cell(self, row, col, verbose=False):
        '''
        Return a specific cell of the matrix.
        '''
        if verbose ==  True:
            print(f'cell[row={row}, col={col}]...')
            print(self.matrix[row][col])
        return self.matrix[row][col]

    def write_cell(self, row, col, data, verbose=False):
        '''
        Assign some data to a specific cell of the matrix.
        '''
        self.matrix[row][col] = data
        if verbose ==  True:
            print('Data wrote into cell[row={row}, col={col}]...')
            print(self.matrix[row][col])                            
        return self.matrix[row][col]
```

Test:

```
print('#########')
m = Matrix2D()
m.generate(4,5,True)
m.printme()
m.get_row(1,True)
m.get_col(1,True)
m.get_cell(3,2,True)
m.write_cell(3,2, (9,9,9),True)
```

Output:

```
#########
Generated a 4 row/s by 5 column/s matrix
----------------------------------------
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
----------------------------------------
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
matrix[row=1]...
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
matrix[col=1]...
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
cell[row=3, col=2]...
(3, 2)
Data wrote into cell[row={row}, col={col}]...
(9, 9, 9)
```

Next, you can add some extra methods for more fancy operations like matrix multiplication, transposition etc... Have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much! I know it's a non-specific and very basic question, but I'm a beginner and I find it very useful to see practical examples of applications. 
@alec_djinn

Comment: @Steren Yes, I have imagined that. That's why I have answered. However, googling a bit would have probably helped as well. Try showing some effort in solving your problem next time. Good luck and happy learning.

Comment: Is there a way to define a user-friendly function for item assignment using such a class, let's say, trying to manually redefine `m[1,3] = (2,4)`?

Comment: @Olivier you can do `m.matrix[1][3] = (2,4)` or add a `__setitem__` method. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__getitem__-and-__setitem__-in-python/

Comment: @alec_djinn Thanks for the tip (even though the correct link is [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__getitem__-and-__setitem__-in-python/)) but I may have been unclear : I'm looking for a way to overload the assignment `=operator` on a complex class (as in `m(0,0) = 2`), without the workaround of a new "textual" own-defined setter (which is what I'm doing so far). I will keep on looking around but I'm ending up thinking this is impossible in Python.

Comment: Actually, I've finally managed to get what I want. It *basically* boils down to the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457300/7009806) (but it's quite more complex in my case because my actual project involves C++ classes wrapped in Python thanks to SWIG).