# Universal override property

Tags: python-3.x

In Python3, I would like to create a class with an override-property, so after instantiation, the instance will behave like whatever it is being assigned, unless its override property is assigned something else than None, in which case it will behave like what has been assigned to the override property. E.g.

```
x = OverrideClass()
x = 1
print(x) -> 1
x.override = “abc“
print(x) -> abc
x = 2
print(x) -> abc
x.override = None
print(x) -> 2
```

Can this be done? From what I've learned by now, it is not possible to override the `x = y` assignment. So the only way would be to modify Python's built-in classes in question. Adding an override-property to int and float would probably do in my application. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to override the assignment ('=') operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456448/is-it-possible-to-override-the-assignment-operator-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if that answer is correct, namely that there is no way to override the `x = y` assignment, then it is probably impossible to achieve what I want... unless I can somehow modify Python's native classes, that is...